# clicking text should click the radio button in HTML

Tags: html

I have this radio button,

```
 <form class="w3-container w3-card-4">
  <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
  <p>
  <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender"  value="male" checked>
  <label >Male</label></p>
  <p>
  <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender"  value="female">
  <label >Female</label></p>
  <p>
  <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="" disabled>
   <label>Don't know (Disabled)</label></p>
 </form>
```

The problem is when I click on the label text the radio button is not selected. is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add id for the radio buttons and for keyword near label boxes.

```
  <form class="w3-container w3-card-4">
   <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
   <p>
   <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" id="m1" value="male" checked>
   <label for="m1">Male</label></p>
   <p>
   <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" id="m2" value="female">
   <label for="m2">Female</label></p>
   <p>
   <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="" disabled>
   <label>Don't know (Disabled)</label></p>
 </form>
```

Now you click the text label the radio button gets selected.

Comment: You can also surround the input with the label and forgo the id and for attributes: `<label><input ... /> Text</label>`

Answer (score 1):

Your form inputs need an ID and your labels need to reference that.

So for example:

```
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender"  value="male" checked id="gender-male">
<label for="gender-male">Male</label></p>
```

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element)

> The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the same Document as the label element. If the attribute is specified and there is an element in the Document whose ID is equal to the value of the for attribute, and the first such element is a labelable element, then that element is the label element's labeled control.

Answer (score 1):

you need to include input inside label tag.

```html
 <form class="w3-container w3-card-4">
  <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
  <p>
  <label > <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender"  value="male" checked>
  Male</label></p>
  <p>
   <label ><input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender"  value="female">
 Female</label></p>
  <p>
 <label> <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="" >
   Don't know (Disabled)</label></p>
 </form>
```

Comment: also, I think using <p> to align the checkbox in a line is not the best way to do that. you can use display block to fix that =>   label{ display: block;}